# Restful API failing sporadically but "catch" statement is always called, even when it does not fail

Tags: reactjs, ajax

We are using a restful API to retrieve information about esports matches being played. From time to time the page simply loads, with no info being returned form the API.

I am fairly confident that the issue is with the API itself, but wanted to double-check that we are not doing anything wrong. Please see our code below:

```
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const url = "http://datafeed.bet/en/esports.json ";

    fetch(proxyurl + url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const list = data;

        const games =
          list &&
          list.Sport &&
          list.Sport.Events &&
          list.Sport.Events.map((match) =>
            match.Name.substr(0, match.Name.indexOf(","))
          );

        const uniqueGames = [...new Set(games)];

        let combinedMatches = [];
        data &&
          data.Sport &&
          data.Sport.Events &&
          data.Sport.Events.map((game) => {
            game.Matches.map((match) => {
              match.Logo = game.Logo;
              match.TournamentName = game.Name;
              match.CategoryID = game.CategoryID;
              match.ID = game.ID;
            });
            combinedMatches = combinedMatches.concat(game.Matches);
          });

        this.setState({
          gameData: data,
          games: games,
          uniqueGames: uniqueGames,
          preloading: false,
          filteredGames: combinedMatches,
          allMatches: combinedMatches,
          count: Math.ceil(combinedMatches.length / this.state.pageSize),
        });

        var i;
        let allMatches = 0;
        let temp;

        for (i = 0; i < this.state.filteredGames.length; i++) {
          temp = allMatches =
            allMatches + this.state.filteredGames[i].Matches.length;
        }

        this.setState({ allMatches: allMatches });
      })
      .catch(console.log('error');
```

Something that confuses me is that whether the data is returned or not, the "catch" statement gets called, outputting "error" to the console. I would like to build in some workaround for when the data is not returned. Would this be placed in the "catch" statement? If so, why how do I only let the catch run if the operation actually fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
.catch(console.log('error'))
```

You *immediately* invoke `console.log('error')` and pass its *result* (which is `undefined`) to the `catch`.  In this case it's invoking it right away, before the AJAX operation is even performed.

What you want to pass to `catch` is a function which would invoke that operation if/when it needs to:

```
.catch(e => console.log('error'))
```

As an aside, you'd probably also want to log the error itself so you can see what happened, as opposed to just the string `'error'`:

```
.catch(e => console.log('error', e))
```